# Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>\saved@c@thm \end{frame} Can anyone help me correct this?

Tags: errors

```
\begin{frame}{Math Stuff}
\newtheorem{thm}{Easy Theorem}
\newtheorem{pf}{Proof}
\newtheorem{rmk}{Remark}
\begin{thm}<1->
$$x^n+y^n=z^n,$$
has no integer solutions for $n>2$
where $x,\,y,\,z\,\neq\,0$.
\end{thm}
\begin{pf}<3->
The proof is trivial and left as an exercise.
\end{pf}
\begin{rmk}<2->
This problem was first posed in $10,000$ B.C.
\end{rmk}
```

Comment: Put the three `\newtheorem` definitions into the preamble (before `\begin{document}'). Does this solve your problem?